# How to migrate to Android Aar Library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How do you migrate from *XamarinBuildDownloadRestoreAssemblyAar* to *XamarinBuildDownloadAndroidAarLibrary*? I am not able to build my Xamarin Android app and this warning is being given:

> "`XamarinBuildDownloadRestoreAssemblyAar` is no longer supported. If your build is failing, revert to an older Xamarin.Build.Download version, or migrate your packages to use the new `XamarinBuildDownloadAndroidAarLibrary` ItemGroup. If your build is succeeding it is safe to ignore this warning."

I haven't found the documentation to do so.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/784